# What Does (x) After Calling a Function Mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have the following Python code line:

`x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)`

What does the **(x)** mean?

Comment: `layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")` returns something callable, which is then called with a single argument `x`.

Comment: Looks as if `layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")` returns a function that is then called with `(x)`.

Comment: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/

Comment: Thank you very much! If anybody wants some rep points, please write an answer.

Comment: VTC because there isn't a clear question here. Specifically understanding the effect of the code would depend on context. If it's generally about the syntax, then the question doesn't make sense to ask: putting `(foo)` after something treats the "something" as a callable, and calls it. In the example code, the `(x)` has the **same relationship to** `layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")`, that `(64, activation="relu")` does to `layers.Dense`. It's like asking what the `[z]` in `x[y][z]` means.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel please do! I got what I wanted to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're specifically reading code written using the Keras library's Functional API (as opposed to the Sequential API). What this means is each neural network layer upon creation returns a function that must be called. To create a simple feed-forward neural network in this manner (with no skip-connections),

> a. Create a layer that takes in your input. This yields a *function*
> that takes your input.
> b. Create another layer and pass the previous
> layer in as input.
> ...
> n. Create an output layer that takes the
> second-to-last layer as input.

Or

```
x_in = layers.Input(...)
x_1 = layers.Dense(...)(x_in)
x_2 = layers.Dense(...)(x_1)
x_out = layers.Dense(...)(x_2)
```

You don't need to assign each layer its own variable name, though, so the previous example could be rewritten as (and is commonly in tutorials as such):

```
x = layers.Input(...)
x = layers.Dense(...)(x)
x = layers.Dense(...)(x)
x = layers.Dense(...)(x)
```